# select2 > How to change Prototype Function "MultipleSelection.prototype.selectionContainer"

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I use the jQuery based library Select2.

Within the library https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.js the following function is defined:

```js
  MultipleSelection.prototype.selectionContainer = function () {
    var $container = $(
      '<li class="select2-selection__choice">' +
        '<button type="button" class="select2-selection__choice__remove" ' +
        'tabindex="-1">' +
          '<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>' +
        '</button>' +
        '<span class="select2-selection__choice__display"></span>' +
      '</li>'
    );

    return $container;
  };
```

How can I change/overwrite this function without changing the original file?

Answer (score 0):

```
  window.Select2['class'].multi.prototype.selectionContainer = function () {
    var $container = $(
      '<li class="select2-selection__choice">' +
        '<button type="button" class="select2-selection__choice__remove" ' +
        'tabindex="-1">' +
          '<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>' +
        '</button>' +
        '<span class="select2-selection__choice__display"></span>' +
      '</li>'
    );

    return $container;
  };
```

You can change anything there...